# Getting non unique records with sequel

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm using sequel in my project and I have problem with getting non unique record ids from db.
I have the following table:

```
table = Sequel::Model.db[:csv_temp]
```

and records in that table looks like this:

```
table.all

[{:id=>1,
  :school_identifier=>"school_id_1",
  :school_name=>"school_name_1",
 },
 {:id=>2,
  :school_identifier=>"school_id_1",
  :school_name=>"school_name_2",
 }]
```

How can I get ids of records which school_identifier is not unique?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this, there are probably others:

```
DB[:csv_temp].
  where(:school_identifier=>DB[:csv_temp].
    select_group(:school_identifier).
    having{count{}.* > 2}).
  select_map(:id)
```

Comment: Oops.  Should probably be `>= 2`.